# Drama dialogue, I wanna know the precise meaning

Tags: meaning

I like watching American/English drama. But sometimes there are the dialogues I cannot understand easily.

IN the dialogue below, I want to know the last two sentences(bold). Please help me.

> A: It's all right. How long you been stationed
>   here? Working for North Korea?
>
> B: Nine years.
>
> A: It's a long time. Your kid, was that part of
>   the plan?
>
> B: I get it. **The real world changes things.**
>   **Maybe the life they'd planned for you isn't the life you ended up with.**

Comment: What show was it?

Comment: I think it simply means, **things don't always go according to plan**

Comment: You need to explain what it is you don't understand.  None of the words above is difficult, nor is the sentence construction particularly obscure.

Answer (score 1):

> The real world changes things.  Maybe the life they'd planned for you isn't the life you ended up with.

It might be rephrased: "Experiencing some of the cold hard facts of life  made me change my plans, and settle for less."

It's frustrated ambition.  An emphatic *real world* signifies the conflicted modern secular-minded person's bitterness about the myths they suppose they've abandoned, yet which haunt them still.  The second sentence's leading *maybe* is rhetorical, and emphasizes the speaker's uncertain regret.

Answer (score 0):

"they" could be referring to his parents, who'd had different plans for their son, probably having him work closer to home. He may not have planned to become a father, but when the baby was on the way, he realized he had no other choice.